# Remove item from list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove all the `li` from my unordered list but I want to keep the `li` before the last `li` anybody an idea how it's done ?

I now have

```
$('.pagination ul li:not(:last)').remove();
```

but that removes everything but the last one so it isn't correct

Comment: I would recommend using the solution by Kevin Bowersox. His solution might not be the shortest, but its the most efficient solution in here. The code by Bojangles is nice and clean but also the slowest method posted in here.

Feel free to look over the testing result:

http://jsperf.com/jquery-list-filter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) with a negative index - this will count from the *end* of the collection instead of the beginning.

In your case, you'll want to use an index of `-2` (`-1` would be the last `<li>`), like so:

```
$('.pagination ul li:not(:eq(-2))').remove();
```

[Here's a quick demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/mj79g/).

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? The example I gave [works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/mj79g/) with jQuery 1.9.1

Comment: @user1994529: Then you are doing something wrong somehow. The code is syntactically correct.

Comment: Do note that this picks the second last element from the collection, whatever that may be (not necessarily the element preceding the last list item). In cases with nested lists for example, this would probably fail. Works in this case though.

Comment: @Asad In which case you'd just change the first bit of the selector to `.pagination ul > li`

Comment: @Bojangles Yes. I was just noting that so that people would be aware of the difference between `:eq` and `:nth-child`.

Comment: ``:nth-child`` would also possibly select other elements ``:nth-child-of-type`` would also take care of this.

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completeness in this answer, here's another (arguably more readable) method:

```
$('.pagination ul li:last-child').prev().siblings().remove();
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/bBxDL/1

Comment: -1 `I want to remove all the li from my unordered list but I want to keep the li before the last li`. This does the opposite.

Comment: @Curt Has been corrected. This is actually a bit safer than the top voted answer in the general case, since it always selects the list item that is the second last child and removes everything else.

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript**

```
var $items = $('.pagination ul li');

$items.not($items.eq($items.length-2)).remove();
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="pagination">
    <ul>
        <li>Page 1</li>
        <li>Page 2</li>
        <li>Page 3</li>
        <li>Page 4</li>
        <li>Page 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/B8NPV/

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use `nth-last-of-type` to fetch the one before the last. Attached jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zjLph/

**HTML**

```
<div class="pagination">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.pagination ul li').filter(':not(:nth-last-of-type(2))').remove();
```